# Are there any example data sets for Python?

Tags: python, dataset

For quick testing, debugging, creating portable examples, and benchmarking, R has available to it a large number of data sets (in the Base R `datasets` package). The command `library(help="datasets")` at the R prompt describes nearly 100 historical datasets, each of which have associated descriptions and metadata.

Is there anything like this for Python?

Comment: sure just go google ... "dataset csv" and import it with the csv module ...

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417293/sample-datasets-in-pandas

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc.html) package to access all R datasets from Python.

Set up the interface:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
>>> def data(name): 
...    return pandas2ri.ri2py(r[name])
```

Then call `data()` with any dataset's name of the available datasets (just like in `R`)

```
>>> df = data('iris')
>>> df.describe()
       Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width
count    150.000000   150.000000    150.000000   150.000000
mean       5.843333     3.057333      3.758000     1.199333
std        0.828066     0.435866      1.765298     0.762238
min        4.300000     2.000000      1.000000     0.100000
25%        5.100000     2.800000      1.600000     0.300000
50%        5.800000     3.000000      4.350000     1.300000
75%        6.400000     3.300000      5.100000     1.800000
max        7.900000     4.400000      6.900000     2.500000
```

To see a list of the available datasets with a description for each:

```
>>> print(r.data())
```

Note: rpy2 requires `R` installation with setting `R_HOME` variable, and [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) must be installed as well.

## UPDATE

I just created [PyDataset](https://github.com/iamaziz/PyDataset), which is a simple module to make loading a dataset from Python as easy as `R`'s (and it does not require `R` installation, only `pandas`).

To start using it, install the module:

```
$ pip install pydataset
```

Then just load up any dataset you wish (currently around 757 datasets available):

```
from pydataset import data

titanic = data('titanic')
```

Answer (score 23):

There are also datasets available from the [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html) library.

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

There are multiple datasets within this package. Some of the *Toy Datasets* are:

```
load_boston()          Load and return the boston house-prices dataset (regression).
load_iris()            Load and return the iris dataset (classification).
load_diabetes()        Load and return the diabetes dataset (regression).
load_digits([n_class]) Load and return the digits dataset (classification).
load_linnerud()        Load and return the linnerud dataset (multivariate regression).
```

Answer (score 11):

I originally posted this over at the related question [Sample Datasets in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417293/sample-datasets-in-pandas/29956221#29956221), but since it is relevant outside pandas I am including it here as well.

There are many ways that are now available for accessing sample data sets in Python. Personally, I tend to stick with whatever package I am
already using (usually seaborn or pandas). If you need offline access,
installing the data set with Quilt seems to be the only option.

## Seaborn

The brilliant plotting package `seaborn` has several built-in sample data sets.

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.head()
```

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

## Pandas

If you do not want to import `seaborn`, but still want to access [its sample
data sets](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data), you can read the seaborn sample data from its URL:

```
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
```

Note that the sample data sets containing categorical columns have their [column
type modified by `sns.load_dataset()`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/10bdb18f47bb5fc0a30d34954ff6f174b4cf5881/seaborn/utils.py#L396) and the result might not be the same
by getting it from the url directly. The iris and tips sample data sets are also
available in the pandas github repo [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/pandas/tests/data).

## R sample datasets

Since any dataset can be read via `pd.read_csv()`, it is possible to access all
R's sample data sets by copying the URLs from [this R data set
repository](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html).

Additional ways of loading the R sample data sets include
[`statsmodel`](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/datasets/index.html)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris').data
```

and [`PyDataset`](https://github.com/iamaziz/PyDataset)

```
from pydataset import data

iris = data('iris')
```

## scikit-learn

`scikit-learn` returns sample data as numpy arrays rather than a pandas data
frame.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
# `iris.data` holds the numerical values
# `iris.feature_names` holds the numerical column names
# `iris.target` holds the categorical (species) values (as ints)
# `iris.target_names` holds the unique categorical names
```

## Quilt

[Quilt](https://quiltdata.com/) is a dataset manager created to facilitate
dataset management. It includes many common sample datasets, such as
[several](https://quiltdata.com/package/uciml/) from the [uciml sample
repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php). The [quick start
page](https://docs.quiltdata.com/get-started/quick-start) shows how to install
and import the iris data set:

```
# In your terminal
$ pip install quilt
$ quilt install uciml/iris
```

After installing a dataset, it is accessible locally, so this is the best option if you want to work with the data offline.

```
import quilt.data.uciml.iris as ir

iris = ir.tables.iris()
```

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width        class
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
```

Quilt also support dataset versioning and include a [short
description](https://quiltdata.com/package/uciml/iris/) of each dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Following Joran's comment, I've since found the [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) module, which provides its own `datasets` package. The [online documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/datasets/index.html) shows an example of how to import datasets available in R:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
duncan_prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "car")
print duncan_prestige.__doc__
```

Comment: `ValueError: Dataset Duncan was not found.` statsmodels 0.9

Answer (score 1):

MyMVPA is another module which provides easy access to databases. You can check the link below.

```
>>> from mvpa2.tutorial_suite import *
>>> data = [[  1,  1, -1],
...         [  2,  0,  0],
...         [  3,  1,  1],
...         [  4,  0, -1]]
>>> ds = Dataset(data)
>>> ds.shape
(4, 3)
>>> len(ds)
4
```

Example from the link

http://www.pymvpa.org/tutorial_datasets.html

Answer (score 0):

Concretely, using @tmthydvnprt example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

The actual dataset can be called by doing `iris.data`.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/

**Running Python 3.5**