# Sample datasets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, sample-data

When using R it's handy to load "practice" datasets using

```
data(iris)
```

or

```
data(mtcars)
```

Is there something similar for Pandas? I know I can load using any other method, just curious if there's anything builtin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any example data sets for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579407/are-there-any-example-data-sets-for-python)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Since I originally wrote this answer, I have updated it with the many ways that are now available for accessing sample data sets in Python. Personally, I tend to stick with whatever package I am
already using (usually seaborn or pandas). If you need offline access,
installing the data set with Quilt seems to be the only option.

## Seaborn

The brilliant plotting package `seaborn` has several built-in sample data sets.

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.head()
```

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

## Pandas

If you do not want to import `seaborn`, but still want to access [its sample
data sets](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data), you can use  @andrewwowens's approach for the seaborn sample
data:

```
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
```

Note that the sample data sets containing categorical columns have their [column
type modified by `sns.load_dataset()`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/10bdb18f47bb5fc0a30d34954ff6f174b4cf5881/seaborn/utils.py#L396) and the result might not be the same
by getting it from the url directly. The iris and tips sample data sets are also
available in the pandas github repo [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/pandas/tests/data).

## R sample datasets

Since any dataset can be read via `pd.read_csv()`, it is possible to access all
R's sample data sets by copying the URLs from [this R data set
repository](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html).

Additional ways of loading the R sample data sets include
[`statsmodel`](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/datasets/index.html#datasets)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris').data
```

and [`PyDataset`](https://github.com/iamaziz/PyDataset)

```
from pydataset import data

iris = data('iris')
```

## scikit-learn

`scikit-learn` returns sample data as numpy arrays rather than a pandas data
frame.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
# `iris.data` holds the numerical values
# `iris.feature_names` holds the numerical column names
# `iris.target` holds the categorical (species) values (as ints)
# `iris.target_names` holds the unique categorical names
```

## Quilt

[Quilt](https://quiltdata.com/) is a dataset manager created to facilitate
dataset management. It includes many common sample datasets, such as
[several](https://quiltdata.com/package/uciml/) from the [uciml sample
repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php). The [quick start
page](https://docs.quiltdata.com/get-started/quick-start) shows how to install
and import the iris data set:

```
# In your terminal
$ pip install quilt
$ quilt install uciml/iris
```

After installing a dataset, it is accessible locally, so this is the best option if you want to work with the data offline.

```
import quilt.data.uciml.iris as ir

iris = ir.tables.iris()
```

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width        class
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
```

Quilt also support dataset versioning and include a [short
description](https://quiltdata.com/package/uciml/iris/) of each dataset.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer just be NO, there isn't a handy "practice" datasets you can load with pandas.

Comment: You should really check out the answer by @cheng10 below

Answer (score 42):

The builtin pandas testing DataFrame is very convenient.

makeMixedDataFrame():

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
Out[23]:
     A    B     C          D
0  0.0  0.0  foo1 2009-01-01
1  1.0  1.0  foo2 2009-01-02
2  2.0  0.0  foo3 2009-01-05
3  3.0  1.0  foo4 2009-01-06
4  4.0  0.0  foo5 2009-01-07
```

other testing DataFrame options：

makeDataFrame():

```
In [24]: pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame().head()
Out[24]:
                   A         B         C         D
acKoIvMLwE  0.121895 -0.781388  0.416125 -0.105779
jc6UQeOO1K -0.542400  2.210908 -0.536521 -1.316355
GlzjJESv7a  0.921131 -0.927859  0.995377  0.005149
CMhwowHXdW  1.724349  0.604531 -1.453514 -0.289416
ATr2ww0ctj  0.156038  0.597015  0.977537 -1.498532
```

makeMissingDataframe()：

```
In [27]: pd.util.testing.makeMissingDataframe().head()
Out[27]:
                   A         B         C         D
qyXLpmp1Zg -1.034246  1.050093       NaN       NaN
v7eFDnbQko  0.581576  1.334046 -0.576104 -0.579940
fGiibeTEjx -1.166468 -1.146750 -0.711950 -0.205822
Q8ETSRa6uY  0.461845 -2.112087  0.167380 -0.466719
7XBSChaOyL -1.159962 -1.079996  1.585406 -1.411159
```

makeTimeDataFrame()：

```
In [28]: pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame().head()
Out[28]:
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03 -0.641226  0.912964  0.308781  0.551329
2000-01-04  0.364452 -0.722959  0.322865  0.426233
2000-01-05  1.042171  0.005285  0.156562  0.978620
2000-01-06  0.749606 -0.128987 -0.312927  0.481170
2000-01-07  0.945844 -0.854273  0.935350  1.165401
```

Comment: Your answer is underrated- although perhaps it's not exactly what the question was asking for, what I really want is an interactive way to get a dataframe to play with. Thanks!

Comment: @cheng10 this answer is deprecated.

Comment: @G.Macia: Can you explain? these would likely have been replaced if this calling method is deprecated?

Comment: What's to explain? As @G.Macia states, Pandas deprecated the entirety of the `pandas.util.testing` submodule – including *all* of the functionality called above. Ergo, this answer no longer applies. There are no well-maintained alternatives to this functionality (that I know of), but Pandas developers don't appear to especially care. Concerned data scientists (*this means you!*) should begin banging on the Pandas issue tracker about this.

Comment: The package was moved to `pandas._testing`. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html?highlight=maketimedataframe) for an example.

Answer (score 16):

Any publically available .csv file can be loaded into pandas extremely quickly using its URL. Here is an example using the iris dataset originally from the UCI archive.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.head()
```

The output here being the .csv file header you just loaded from the given URL.

```
>>> df.head()
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

A memorable short URL for the same is `https://j​.mp/iriscsv`. This short URL will work only if it's typed and not if it's copy-pasted.

Comment: The website is not down. Check https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris for description, or download `iris.names`

Answer (score 15):

The [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc.html) module is made for this:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

r['iris'].head()
```

yields

```
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

---

Up to pandas 0.19 you could use pandas' own [`rpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/r_interface.html) interface:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as rcom
iris = rcom.load_data('iris')
print(iris.head())
```

yields

```
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

---

`rpy2` also provides a way [to convert `R` objects into Python objects](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/generated_rst/pandas.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.conversion as conversion
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

R = ro.r

df = conversion.ri2py(R['mtcars'])
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
    mpg  cyl  disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs  am  gear  carb
0  21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46   0   1     4     4
1  21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02   0   1     4     4
2  22.8    4   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61   1   1     4     1
3  21.4    6   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44   1   0     3     1
4  18.7    8   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02   0   0     3     2
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was doing this but it violates the "ease" that that the data is available in R. It is a solution that gets it done though!

Comment: Hm? what is so hard about `rcom.load_data('iris')`?

Comment: Likely nothing, I realize I may be being too picky. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Note that `pandas.rpy` was [removed in 0.20](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes). To interface with R, `rpy2` is the recommended option.

Answer (score 4):

I made some public datasets available in [this github repo](https://github.com/practiceprobs/datasets). You can load them via `pd.read_csv(url_to_file.csv)`

### iris

```
iris = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/practiceprobs/datasets/main/iris/iris.csv")
iris.head()
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width      species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
```

### mnist

```
mnist = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/practiceprobs/datasets/main/MNIST/mnist.csv")
mnist.head()
   label  1x1  1x2  1x3  1x4  1x5  ...  28x23  28x24  28x25  28x26  28x27  28x28
0      7    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0
1      2    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0
2      1    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0
3      0    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0
4      4    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0
[5 rows x 785 columns]
```

### netflix titles

```
netflix = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/practiceprobs/datasets/main/netflix-titles/netflix-titles.csv")
netflix.head()
  show_id  ...                                        description
0      s1  ...  As her father nears the end of his life, filmm...
1      s2  ...  After crossing paths at a party, a Cape Town t...
2      s3  ...  To protect his family from a powerful drug lor...
3      s4  ...  Feuds, flirtations and toilet talk go down amo...
4      s5  ...  In a city of coaching centers known to train I...
[5 rows x 12 columns]
```